# Higher lie groups and groupoids

Tags: higher-category-theory

I have come across the following notions while learning these things myself. Wanted to confirm these ideas.

Smooth ∞
stack or equivalently, lie (smooth) ∞
groupoid is an ∞
stack on the site SmoothMfd (the category of smooth manifolds with smooth maps between them, and the coverage being differentiably good open covers). These smooth groupoids form a (∞,1)
topos Smooth∞
Grpd, the group object being lie ∞
-group. Now, an n-truncated smooth ∞
groupoid is called a Lie n-groupoid. An n-truncated lie ∞
group is a lie (n+1)-group. (Since an ordinary group is a set, therefore it is up in degree by one I guess). Are they correct till now?

I was wondering whether can we define the lie ∞
group to be the 0-connected, pointed lie ∞
groupoid via the delooping hypothesis. Also, the lie n-group can be defined to be the group object in the (n,1) category Lie (n-1)-Grpd consisting of lie (n-1) groupoids, I guess; or the pointed connected lie n-groupoid. These all are equivalent definitions, right? Can someone kindly confirm them? Also, the idea of truncation is not very clear to me.

I have just completed my undergrad in physics, apologies if these doubts sound trivial.